# How can I mount a partition back I unmounted it to Re-Label it Using GParted?

Tags: partitioning, mount, gparted

I unmounted my `/dev/sda1/ext4` partition to change the label, now the mount option in Gparted is grey and i cant use `sudo mount /dev/sda1/ext4` i get an error:

> can't find `/dev/sda1/ext4 in /etc/fstab`
>
> /etc/fstab

```
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 521973360 521971313 248.9G 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       521973758 976769023 454795266 216.9G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       771973120 976769023 204795904  97.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       770021376 771973119   1951744   953M 83 Linux
/dev/sda7       757678080 770019327  12341248   5.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda8       521973760 757676031 235702272 112.4G 83 Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

I hope this is what you are asking for , plus it was mounted on `/media/mickey`

How can i solve this, thanks.

Comment: Did you try rebooting ? Maybe that's a way to make it pick up your changes.

Comment: @JonasCz No I have not tried rebooting, seems like the partition is not listed in fstab so would rebooting solve the problem ?

Comment: @JonasCz No, if there are bad fstab entries or the partition we're talking about is important for the system to boot, rebooting might even fail and lead to more problems I think. It should be avoided until this is fixed if possible.

Comment: # Anytime you edit fstab always do this before rebooting. If no errors it just remounts everything, but if errors you have to fix before rebooting or you may not be able to, Make sure you have partition unmounted if previously mounted when creating new mounts in fstab:
`sudo mount -a`

Comment: @oldfred thank you would put that into practice.

Answer (score 4):

`/dev/sda1/ext4` can not exist. The device name must be only `/dev/sda1`.

Comment: I just tried that, got response error:  `mount: can't find /dev/sda1 in /etc/fstab`

Comment: Please edit your question and add the content of your `/etc/fstab` file as well as which mount point your partition would belong to (e.g. should it be mounted as `/home` or as `/var` or what?) Thanks.

Comment: thank you for the help all i did was restart the system and the partition was visible again.